# why am i getting class type error in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy

this is my code im getting  ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type error here i dont know how to fix it i tried reloading didnt work

```
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout=MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.image=Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(
        text='CLICK HERE',
        pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5},
        size_hint=(None,None))
        )
        self.capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video,1.0/30.0)
        return layout
    def load_video(self,*args):
        ret, frame=self.capture.read()
        self.image_frame=frame
        buffer= cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfat='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture=texture

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run only one Kivy application at the same python execution try to restart the kernel or close the platform and reopen it.

Comment: theres only one kivy application

Comment: Consotools>preferences>run>execute in an external system terminal and then click ok. (run with F5)

Comment: i did that its still not working